# Div ocupa toda a largura da tela

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou construindo um layout onde há uma barra no alto da tela que toca de um lado a outro. Usei a propriedade `witdh:100%;`, porém não obtive um resultado satisfatório. O corpo da página está cobrindo a tela inteira, mas tanto essa barra de cima quanto a que se encontra no final da página não estão realmente em 100%, ambas deixam um espaço em branco, como posso resolver?

[image: como nesta foto]

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o CSS que tá usando. Se está 100% era pra tocar de um lado ao outro.

Comment: provavelmente está faltando apenas um clearfix no em seu elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utilize um reset css como por exemplo:

```
* {
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Ou voce pode so setar a margin da barra pra 0 e o padding do body pra 0.

Comment: Vlw amigo, resolveu meu problema

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

Comment: @RenatoJunior O que esse `*` faz precisamente?

Comment: * seleciona todos os elementos da página