# Fazer div ocupar o resto da tela

Tags: html5, css3

Boa tarde, já tentei de varias formas e não consegui fazer com que a div container ocupe 100% da tela (altura).

Acima tenho outra div.

[image: Quero que o texto roxo ocupe 100% da altura e não apareça o pedaço escuro no fim da pagina]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: var(--white);
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    font-family: --apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
html, body, #root{
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: var(--dark);
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: blue;
}
.container img{
        align-self: center;
        width: 450px;
    } 
.container h1{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 90px;
    }
.container p{
        margin-top: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
.container a{
        align-self: center;
        margin-top: 40px;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        background: red;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 15%;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 7px;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
.container a:hover{
        background: purple;
    }
div.containerdois{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
}

div.header{
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
div.header h1{
    color: green;
    font-size: 50px;
}
div.header p{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: end;
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.actions{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 80px;
    }
div.actions a {
        color: purple;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
div.actions button{
        padding: 15px 20px;
        background: red;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 7px;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
div.actions a:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
div.actions button:hover{
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<div="containerdois">
           <div class="header">
                <h1>NearPay</h1>
                <p>By &lt;/IMM&gt; Telecom</p>
           </div>
           <div class="Actions">
                <a href="https://google.pt/">Sou Vendedor</a>
                <a href="https://google.pt/">Aplicação</a>
                <a href="https://google.pt/">Criar uma conta</a>
                <button>
                    Iniciar Sessão
                </button>
           </div>
       </div>
<div class="container">
           <img src="https://3oicpu3giiud1g8ipd3781mi-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/404-error-1.svg" title="Erro 404" alt="Erro 404" /> 
            <h1>Erro 404 - Pagina não encontrada!</h1>
            <p>Pelos vistos a pagina que procuras não anda por aqui.</p>
            <a href="/">
                Voltar para a pagina inicial
            </a>
       </div>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Div ocupa toda a largura da tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235939/div-ocupa-toda-a-largura-da-tela)

Comment: Não, peço desculpa, inicialmente esqueci me de referir que estava a falar em altura. Já tentei varias coisa height: 100vh, 100% e nada funciona, ou ultrapassa o tamanho da tela.

Comment: Experimentei também fazer isto: height: calc(100vh - (o tamanho da div "containerdois" em px)) mas isso não fica responsivo.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que os elementos dentro da div container estão definidos em um tamanho muito grande, uma sugestão é diminuir o tamanho da imagem para width: 250px; e remover ou diminuir o font-size do h1. Isso vai deixar a altura da div dentro da altura maxima da tela.